# Python code Always returning None boolean when False should be returned

Tags: python, python-3.10

```
    import random
    def gameres(comp, you):
        if comp == you:
            return None
# when comp = r
        elif comp == 'r':
            if you == 'p':
                return True
        elif comp == 'r':
            if you == 's':
                return False
# when comp = p
        elif comp == 'p':
            if you == 's':
                return True
        elif comp == 'p':
            if you == 'r':
                return False
# when comp = s
        elif comp == 's':
            if you == 'r':
                return True
        elif comp == 's':
            if you == 'p':
                return False
    
    print("Comp turn: Rock(r), Paper(p) and Scissor(s)")
    randno = random.randint(1, 3)
    if randno == 1:
        comp = 'r'
    elif randno == 2:
        comp = 'p'
    elif randno == 3:
        comp = 's'
    
    you = input("Your turn: Rock(r), Paper(p) and Scissor(s)")
    a = gameres(comp, you)
    
    print(f"Computer chose {comp}")
    print(f"You chose {you}")
    
    if a == None:
        print("The game is a tie!")
    elif a == True:
        print("You Win!")
    elif a == False:
        print("You Lose!")
```

I tried to create a rock paper and scissor game in Python but I'd seen a problem whenever I should lose, it returns "The game is a tie".

I think it is always returning None instead of False.

Comment: If you have the same condition twice in an if/elif/else statement only the _first one_ actually gets entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one flaw that is making it behave this way
Like here if comp is `'r'` and you is `'s'` so `elif comp == 'r':` is true so it will go inside First Part but then when you is not equal to `'p'` it won't return anything and won't check for second elif case (second part).

```
        elif comp == 'r': # First part
            if you == 'p':
                return True
        elif comp == 'r': # Second Part
            if you == 's':
                return False
```

Try to do something like

```
        elif comp == 'r': # First part
            if you == 'p':
                return True
            elif you == 's':
                return False
```

Answer (score 0):

As per jonrsharpe's comment, it makes no sense to have the *same* condition twice in an `if/elif`. Also, you don't need an `elif` at all if you have a `return` in the `if` block.

And finally, given a computer player choice you may simply check for the human player winning choice, and return the result of that check. So your function can be simplified like this:

```py
    def gameres(comp, you):
        if comp == you:
            return None
# when comp = r
        if comp == 'r':
            return you == 'p':
# when comp = p
        if comp == 'p':
            return you == 's':
# when comp = s
        if comp == 's':
            return you == 'r':
```